# Are there mystical underpinnings to Maccabi?

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, chanuka, mysticism-kabbalah, beshalach

One of the explanations I have heard for the title מכבי is that it is an acronym for the pasuk 'מִי-כָמֹכָה בָּאֵלִם ה ([Shemos 15:11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0215.htm)). Is there any reason, mystical or otherwise that that pasuk (or part of the pasuk) specifically was chosen?

Comment: Is your question assuming that the Pasuk was assigned to the name by someone later to give some sort of significance to the fighters' cause, or are you assuming that the Maccabim chose the name based on the Pasuk's significance?

Comment: @SethJ for what it's worth, the text of 1Maccabees 2:4 indicates that they gave themselves this appellation - http://st-takla.org/pub_Deuterocanon/Deuterocanon-Apocrypha_El-Asfar_El-Kanoneya_El-Tanya__8-First-of-Maccabees.html#Chapter 2

Comment: See the Shaloh HaKodesh
See Munkatcher sefarim - Darchei Emunah on Channukah

Comment: Is that your assumption then in your question?  I ask because it's unclear (to me) if that's the question..